# Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a FunctionType)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been using Isolates for a while now, but ever since Flutter 2.5.0 I get the following error

Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a FunctionType)

Its unclear what has changed in all stable branch versions since 2.5.0 that has caused this to occur. I have been using the same compute method for some time and it has worked without any issue. I would love to correct what might be causing the issue but I cannot find any detail pertaining to this issue. Has anyone else seen this issue and subsequently found a solution?

```
Future<Map> callReportSubmit(Map myMap) {
  return compute(submitReport, myMap);
}
```

this is my calling method, it is a top Level function calling another top-level function. The map contains a datetime, 2 strings and 1 object.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the really good info guys, it turns out that Flutter 2.5.0 and up seems to be enforcing the parameter types even when wrapped in a map. This was implied before, but not enforced. encoding my object to json then decoding once inside of my isolate resolved the issue. please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134777/flutter-can-you-send-objects-as-a-message-with-compute) along with the other suggestions above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html Compute() returns eventually the value returned by the callback you passed as argument to the isolate.

try making your function asynchron:

```
 Future<Map> callReportSubmit(Map myMap) async{
   return await compute(submitReport, myMap);
}
```

Comment: try reading this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232371/13801829